# Replacing Display flex (not working for IE) from html element without affecting the output result

Tags: html, css

Having the following html, I want to remove `display flex` whithout affecting the output result. `display:flex` is **NOT** working on Internet Explorer. Keep in mind that I can't change the structure of the html elements. I can only add stylesheet.

```html
<table id="TabsTable" width="100%" style="overflow: hidden !important;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="vdcTabs" style="width: 100%;">
                <span id="Tab_dlTabs" style="display: flex;">
                    <span>
                        <div class="ActiveTab">
                            <a id="lnktab1">Tab1</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab2" style="">Tab2</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab3" style="">Tab3</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab4" style="">Tab4</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab5" style="">Tab5</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: flex does work in IE10+. Also what is the look you are trying to acheive? To me it just looks like text in a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:table` to `#Tab_dlTabs` and `display:table-cell.` to `#Tab_dlTabs > span`

It works in all browser.

```css
#Tab_dlTabs > span {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table id="TabsTable" width="100%" style="overflow: hidden !important;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="vdcTabs" style="width: 100%;">
                <span id="Tab_dlTabs" style="display: table;">
                    <span>
                        <div class="ActiveTab">
                            <a id="lnktab1">Tab1</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab2" style="">Tab2</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab3" style="">Tab3</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab4" style="">Tab4</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab5" style="">Tab5</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** If you can don't apply inline css.

Comment: Could `display:table-cell` break the table layout if there are more rows? I think its a bad idea

Comment: @GiannisGrivas Yes it's working in IE. You can check it out with all browser.

Comment: @CodeiSir i think `display:inlin-block` break not `display:table-cell`.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas You can check/test your self as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want!?

Works in every Browser and is as close as you can get to `flex`

```css
#Tab_dlTabs > span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="TabsTable" width="100%" style="overflow: hidden !important;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="vdcTabs" style="width: 100%;">
                <span id="Tab_dlTabs" style="">
                    <span>
                        <div class="ActiveTab">
                            <a id="lnktab1">Tab1</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab2" style="">Tab2</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab3" style="">Tab3</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab4" style="">Tab4</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <div class="VdcTab">
                            <a id="lnktab5" style="">Tab5</a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```